# Using the "in" operator, brackets vs. curly brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is simple example of checking variable across multiple values:

```
var = "a"
if var == "a" or var == "b" or var == "c":
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

After a small reseach, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values/15112149#15112149) another, more advanced approach by Martijn Pieters:

```
var = "a"
if var in {"a", "b", "c"}:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

But also, in the link I posted above, it is stated that brackets are also acceptable:

```
if var in ("a", "b", "c"):
```

What is the difference between curly brackets `{...}` and `(...)` brackets here?

And if it is possible to answer, what is the best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...}` creates a set while `(...)` will create a tuple for you (the actual tuple creation token is the comma (,)). For small data, there is probably no perceptible difference.

When doing an `in` check with a set, the hash value of the `var` is calculated and used as basis for an index while when doing a membership test with a tuple, the tuple is searched from start till `var` is found or not found.

Answer (score 1):

The first, i.e `{...}` denotes/creates a `set`, using `in` with a set you'd be performing a set membership operation which results in `O(1)` complexity.

`(...)`, on the other hand, denotes/creates a `tuple`. Searching for membership with `in` in a `tuple` is `O(N)` since it goes through every element in the `tuple` perfoming a check to see if there's a match.

In a small case such as your, this arguably won't make much of a difference (unless in a tight loop). In general, you should prefer `{...}` since it isn't really harder to type and has the perk of being efficient.